# modal not sliding from top

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I implemented the bootstrap model in my website.....
the model is working fine but the model does not slide from top exactly like the actual bootstrap model....
How to fix it....

Actual model

http://jsfiddle.net/nJ6Mw/1/

model not sliding from top

http://jsfiddle.net/y88WX/embedded/result/

```
<div id="example" class="modal hide fade in" style="display: block;" aria-hidden="false">
    <div class="modal-header"> <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
        <h3>This is a Modal Heading</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <h4>Text in a modal</h4>
        <p>You can add some text here.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer"> <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Call to action</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your options variable is not defined in jsfiddle, try implementing them directly into the javascript panel provided.

Comment: @ShannonHochkins: thanks for your reply can u update in the fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have got way too many resources conflicting in the fiddle that you're trying to get working, this fiddle works, so if you can put this code into the page that you're trying to load it into and it doesn't work, you know the problem isn't your bootstrap, also, please send a link to the page you're having problems with, please don't send a fiddle with many different resources attached.

You need to define options for the modal via javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $('#event-modal').modal({
        backdrop: true;
    });
});
```

Placing all css and links/html from the site directly into fiddle is not easy for someone to jump into and debug for you.

http://jsfiddle.net/sfWBT/1/

Comment: i updated my removed unnecessary code http://jsfiddle.net/y88WX/5/embedded/result/

Comment: where should i need to put this in my code $(function() {
    $('#event-modal').modal({
        backdrop: true;
    });
});